# How can I instantiate a class from an object that shares its interface?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

I want to instantiate a class from an object that has the exact same shape as the class.

This is what I'm trying:

```
// The generic type of the object the constructor will use
type PropObj<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] };

class Item {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;

  constructor(propObj: PropObj<Item>) {

    // loop through all keys inside `propObj` and use it to assign Item's values
    for (const key in propObj) {

      const val = propObj[key]; // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'PropObj<Item>' has no index signature.
      this[key] = val; // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Item' has no index signature.
    }
  }
}
```

However inside the loop `val` has type `any` here because `type 'PropObj<Item>' has no index signature`.

Why doesn't TS understand that `propObj[key]` has type `T[K]`, and how can I get it to do so?

Comment: Thinking its the way generics are done with typescript.  Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135069/typescript-generic-type-check-not-working-as-expected, the first response links away to documentation explanation

Comment: [Relevant Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12314)

Comment: @CRice does that issue mean there is no way to iterate over objects while maintaining exact type safety?

Comment: You can always specify the type manually. For your example, declaring `let key: keyof typeof propObj;` before the loop, then `for (key in propObj) { ... }` will fix your two "implicit any" errors. But in general, I think you're right, there is no way to get *exact* type safety when looping an object.

Comment: Thanks @CRice that sorted it! But why doesn't the for..in loop do that automatically? Can't it work out `key`'s type by itself?

Comment: As they mention in the issue, it could, but that's not sound since the object you iterate over might have additional keys at runtime that typescript isn't aware of.